# Rewrite landing pages from one directory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have about 30 landing page directories in my site's root directory, and for neatness I want to move all the files to a /landing directory. I want all the public vanity URLs for the landing pages still to work and NOT to show the 'landing' directory in the address bar.

For instance, I want
www.site.com/happiness

to display content stored in my /landing/happiness directory, but I want the url in the address bar still to show www.site.com/happiness.

What I have in my .htaccess now is

`RewriteRule ^happiness(.*)?$ landing/happiness$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

This shows the content fine but rewrites the URL in the address bar and exposes the 'landing' directory. How do I do the rewrites in the .htaccess so that the files served are in the landing directory but the address bar shows the original vanity URL?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "This shows the content fine but rewrites the URL in the address bar and exposes the 'landing' directory." Nope, it doesn't. You must have a redirect rule somewhere or a redirect mechanism.

Comment: Really? You could be right, but how are you so sure?

Comment: Your rule will only rewrite, not redirect because you're not using the *[R]* flag. Do you have any more .htaccess rules or know if you do any redirects in the application itself?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happens, when you enter a directory URL without a trailing slash, `/happiness` for example or `/happiness/subdir`. In this case, [`mod_dir`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) issues a redirect to the URL *with* a trailing slash.

You can circumvent this, by always adding a trailing slash to the internal redirect

```
RewriteRule ^happiness(?:/.*)?$ landing/$0/ [NC,L,QSA]
```

The downside to this is, you have always a slash at the end, even if it is some PHP file.

Comment: Great! This appears to be working with a new directory I just tried it with. Dirs I was working on earlier today are still redirecting / exposing the /landing directory in the address bar, although that could be something cached somewhere.

Comment: @TonyBrasunas The browser caches the 301 redirects, of course. Maybe restarting the browser or clearing the browser cache might help.